# Слайдер калькулятор - инициализация

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть готовый калькулятор. Как сделать так, что при загрузке страницы, он сразу срабатывал и показывал значение? Сейчас он срабатывает только если его начать двигать(слайдер)

```
function calc(tb){
  var v = document.getElementById("val") ;
  var r = document.getElementById("result");

  v.innerHTML = tb.value;
  r.innerHTML = tb.value*2300*0.27;

}
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="track"  onchange="calc(this);"/>

<div>Значение <span id="val"></span></div>
<div>Стоимость <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка была не `var v = document.getElementById("ex8") ;`
а `var v = document.getElementById("val");`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ex8").slider({
        formatter: function(value) {
            calc(value);

        },
        value: 50,
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        tooltip: 'always'// Slider will instantiate showing 8.12 due to specified precision
    });
});
function calc(value){
    var v = document.getElementById("val");
    var r = document.getElementById("result");
    v.innerHTML = value;
    r.innerHTML = Math.ceil(value*2300*0.27);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<input id="ex8" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>

<div>Значение <span id="val"></span></div>
<div>Стоимость <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто запустите функцию со значением

```js
function calc(tb){
  var v = document.getElementById("val") ;
  var r = document.getElementById("result");

  v.innerHTML = tb.value;
  r.innerHTML = tb.value*2300*0.27;

}

calc(document.getElementById("track"));
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="track"  onchange="calc(this);"/>

<div>Значение <span id="val"></span></div>
<div>Стоимость <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Comment: у меня сделано под бутстраповский слайдер и возвращает NaN.

Comment: так...теперь выдает 0, когда положение слайдера стоит на 50 из 100.

Comment: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/   Example 8

Comment: @RafaelShepard Тогда задайте вопрос с вашим кодом bootstrap slider. С кодом, который вы предоставили инициализация работает?)

Comment: да, работает)))

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение со слайдером Bootstrap

```js
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
 formatter: function(value) {
    calc(value);
 }
});

function calc(value){
  var v = document.getElementById("val") ;
  var r = document.getElementById("result");
  v.innerHTML = value;
  r.innerHTML = value*2300*0.27;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>

<div>Значение <span id="val"></span></div>
<div>Стоимость <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Comment: у меня почему-то при удерживании клика на бегунок выскакивает NaN, а при mouseUp все нормально. И tooltip стал черной чёрточкой...

Comment: @RafaelShepard, Приложите свои код пожалуйста. И еще в каком браузере смотрите?)

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ex8").slider({
        formatter: function(value) {
            calc(value);

        },
        value: 50,
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        tooltip: 'always'// Slider will instantiate showing 8.12 due to specified precision
    });
});
function calc(value){
    var v = document.getElementById("ex8") ;
    var r = document.getElementById("result");
    v.innerHTML = value;
    r.innerHTML = Math.ceil(value*2300*0.27);
}

Comment: https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/WyxYRr лучше так

Comment: смотрю в chrome